# Is everything on HTTP 1.1? My transparent Proxy requires it (becuase of Host:)

Tags: http

I need the `Host:` header for a transparent proxy. And that is only supported by HTTP/1.1. Does everyone use HTTP/1.1?

Comment: Have a look at this [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073392/is-http-1-0-still-in-use) question and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1).** My priority was needing the Host: header. Apparently, most HTTP/1.0 clients just tack it on, so I accept HTTP/1.0, but require a Host: header.